# Есть win1251 и cp1251, почему они написаны по разному?

Tags: кодировка

Почему `win1251` и `cp1251` написаны по-разному?

Comment: в каком контексте вопрос? Почему разные имена? Или вы результаты разные получаете?

Comment: `cp` - от `Code Page`, а `win` - потому что эту кодировку ввели в `windows`-е, в интернете принято такое название `windows-1251`. В одной ранее широко известной базе данных тоже самое называется `cyrr`. Кто как хочет, так и называет. Порой нет единого правила наименования даже в казалось бы единой системе. Одни функции принимают одно название, другие - другое и т.д.

Comment: @Sergey это должен был быть ответ...

Comment: @Sergey если решите самостоятельно опубликовать ответ, сообщите, я удалю свой.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ из комментария:

`cp` - от `Code Page`, а `win` - потому что эту кодировку ввели в `windows`-е, в интернете принято такое название `windows-1251`. В одной ранее широко известной базе данных тоже самое называется `cyrr`. Кто как хочет, так и называет. Порой нет единого правила наименования даже в казалось бы единой системе. Одни функции принимают одно название, другие - другое и т.д.